# How to read single parameter from a file?

Tags: glpk

Chapter 9, page 163, of the [AMPL book](https://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/chapter-downloads/) gives an example of reading a single parameter from a file:

> For example, if you want to read the number of weeks and the
>   hours available each week for our simple production model (Figure 4-4),
>
> `param T > 0;`
>
> `param avail {1..T} >= 0;`
>
> from a file `week_data.txt` containing
>
> `4`
>
> `40 40 32 40`
>
> then you can give the command
>
> `read T, avail[1], avail[2], avail[3], avail[4] <week_data.txt;`

This command fails in GLPK with error `colon missing where expected`. The Modeling Language GNU MathProg Language reference only contains `table data IN`, which serves for reading tabular data. Can GLPK read a single parameter from a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMPL and GMPL are related functional languages. GMPL contains a subset of the AMPL syntax but differs in several areas like the *table* statement.

One way to read a single parameter is to write the data into a file with a certain syntax, e.g. the contents below show a single parameter and a table:

```
param T := 4;

param avail :=
      1 0
      2 1
      3 1
      4 0;

end;
```

To verify the syntax, consider this code in the file `problem.mod`:

```
param T > 0;

param avail {1..T} >= 0;

var use {1..T} >= 0;

maximize usage: sum {t in 1..T} avail[t];

subject to constraint {t in 1..T}: use[t] <= avail[t];

solve;

end;
```

The result shows that it worked:

```
> glpsol -m problem.mod -d problem.dat
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.65
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 -m problem.mod -d problem.dat
Reading model section from problem.mod...
13 lines were read
Reading data section from problem.dat...
9 lines were read
Generating usage...
Generating constraint...
Model has been successfully generated
glp_mpl_build_prob: row usage; constant term 2 ignored
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65
5 rows, 4 columns, 4 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
~     0: obj =   2.000000000e+00  infeas =  0.000e+00
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND BY LP PREPROCESSOR
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 0.1 Mb (110236 bytes)
Model has been successfully processed
```

Comment: GLPK is not a subset of AMPL. E.g. the table statement differs significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the table statement to read parameters from a CSV files or SQL tables.

You can use data files for passing parameters, e.g. see [this example of writing data files in AWK and Visual Basic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Scripting_plus_MathProg#Parametric_studies_and_MathProg).